How can I see the records from the Applications table?
I am trying to see the records for the Applications table in Dataverse environment. Even with administrator permissions, when I browse the Applications table in the Power Apps portal, it shows no records, even if the environment does have some applications in it. I do not get the records by any other means either (i.e. via Dataverse connector in Cloud Flow, API call).
